# How to develop SSL VPN client on iOS platform

Tags: ios, ssl, vpn

I once researched this, but could not get an answer. Basically, It seems private VPN API only open to some special vendor like Cisco, CheckPoint, etc. I just wonder, how could I archive this if I have similar resources like these vendor. We have SSLVPN client on Windows/Mac, our purpose is own our iOS version. How could I archive this, any tip or information are welcome~

Comment: Hi. Did you find answer to your question?